# Storing Booleans in a big 2 dimensional Array

Tags: java, memory, boolean

I need to mark coordinates as accessed in a big 2-dimensional coordinate system. At start all coordinates are false (not accessed). Only a small part of coordinates will be passed during lifetime of the running application.

I thought to store this information in a 2-dim Boolean array.

```
Boolean[][] booleans = new Boolean[200000][200000];
```

But of course this will throw an Java heap space.

Because 99,9% will be ever false, is there another way to store the data in a multidimensional Array, so only the true values needs memory ?

Comment: *99,9% will be ever false* ... you are **not** using primitives.

Comment: You could use a sparse boolean array or use a BitSet

Comment: I can also use primitives, but I thought maybe I could initialize the array with null, which represents false.

Comment: Doing the math, you're looking at 40 million booleans being actually used (200K^2*.001 = 40 million). While that sounds like a lot, some things to consider as an additional layer of @vlad324's approach is to put either a caching layer on top, or a paging/quadrant based approach.  You would only need to load a portion of your universe at any one time. Swap it out for another quadrant. Similar to OS paging files and virtual memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Set<Pair>` where `Pair` is POJO with:

```
private int x;
private int y;
```

And this set stores only values with `true`, so if list doesn't contain `Pair(x, y)` that means it's false.

Comment: I think you mean _...if list does **not** contain..._   Also, use a `Set` instead of List to make it fast retrieval, and add equals/hashCode methods to `Pair`.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good idea, but I guess I will have performance issues to check if a pair is present. I ill have to check.

Comment: Using a `Set` will be O(1) to check if it exists.

Comment: @mcflysoft as mentioned AndrewS use Set instead, and your performance issue will be solved, updated

Comment: @mcflysoft it's easy to verify with a little bit of code. Why guess when you can empirically test it? A lot of bad code has been written in the name of premature optimization based on gut assumptions.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i will check. Also the solution from Hovercraft sounds interresting. Using an Array of bitsets. Bitset[200000] bs; bs[10000].set(10000). I will check and accept.